# How do I make a sidebar on the far end of the viewport, in Bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, sidebar

I'm trying to have a centered column, with a sidebar that's on the far left of the viewport/browser. It doesn't matter if it's sticky or not. I've tried using `position`, but it messes things up. Here's an example of what I'm trying to achieve - [link](https://pixelgrade.com/demos/patch/bikes/the-distinguished-gentlemans-ride/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the grid system properly to reach this job:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-3">
    <!-- sidebar -->
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-9">
    <!-- main content -->
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Changing div class col-xs-9 to 3 and vice versa you'll get the same sidebar that is on stackoverflow. If you want whitespaccing on left and right you must use container instead container-fluid.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

They did it with aside, and set a left margin of -60px. Use inspect elements to take a look into the html and css rules used on an element.